# How to add labels in webgl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webgl

I would like to know how to add labels in graphics plotted using webgl. I tried searching for it, but the search did not yield any result. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: What kind of labels?  Any comparsion to `openGL`?

Comment: http://callum.com/sandbox/webglex/connected_planet/#

Comment: label the lines on the given example